# Параллельная работа нескольких скриптов

Tags: python

Я не совсем понял как реализовать параллельную работу скриптов, так как у меня задача немного не простая. Есть главный скрипт и дочерние 3 штуки. Сделаю все на примере поиска текста в неком масиве предложений.

**Главный:**

```
from script1 import res1
from script2 import res2

def checker():
    list = ['я ищу злое чудеще','оно пролетело над землей','ищу очень долго','может кто видел']

    for txt in list:
        print('Поиск.....')
        print('еще что-то делается.....')
        if txt.find('ищу') > -1:
            res1()
            res2() # дождаться окончания расчетов в res1
        print('не дожидаться окончания расчетов в скриптов в условии...')
        print('еще что-то делается.....')

checker()
```

**Дочерний скрипт1:**

```
def res1():
    print('сделал расчеты для скрипта2 и сохранил в файл.....')
    print('скрипт1 и 2 специально вызываются друг за другом, так бывает что вместо второ вызовится 4.....')
```

**Дочерний скрипт2:**

```
from script1 import res3

def res2():
    print('прочитал файл и сделал расчет для сркипта3.....')
    res3()
```

**Дочерний скрипт3:**

```
def res3():
    print('вывелся отдельно результат.....')
```

Все скрипты специально разделены, так как код расчетов очень большой.
То есть мне нужно, чтобы главный скрипт работал независимо и не дожидаясь результатов других скриптов, а они в свою очередь должны дожидаться друг друга.

Вопрос еще вот в чем, а стоит ли делать это, если процессы очень затратны по памяти нагрузке на процессор? Не факт что чей-то пк (кто решит воспользоваться программой) потянет их паралельную работу (никак не проверю весь свой проект на своем слабом пк, только теоретически тест на маленьких задача).

Вот тут  меня еще как раз вопрос возникает, а сработает ли так, что пока выполняется условие, будет идти работа дальше и оно снова обратиться к условию, которое должно снова запуститься, но при этом старый запуск условия не факт что закончил работу, будет ли два раза вызванное условие работать не зависимо? (хотелось бы)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё просто. Вы можете использовать модуль `multiprocessing`. Вам нужно создать три экземпляра класса `Process` для каждого из дочерних скриптов, и запустить их методом `start()`. Затем, чтобы дождаться завершения выполнения дочерних скриптов, можно вызвать метод `join()` для каждого из процессов.

```
def checker():
    list = ['я ищу злое чудеще','оно пролетело над землей','ищу очень долго','может кто видел']

    for txt in list:
        print('Поиск.....')
        print('еще что-то делается.....')
        if txt.find('ищу') > -1:
            if not hasattr(checker, 'processes_started'):  # проверяем, были ли уже запущены процессы
                p1 = Process(target=res1)
                p2 = Process(target=res2)
                p1.start()
                p2.start()
                p1.join()
                p2.join()
                setattr(checker, 'processes_started', True)  # устанавливаем флаг, что процессы были запущены
        else:
            if hasattr(checker, 'processes_started'):  # если флаг был установлен, сбрасываем его
                delattr(checker, 'processes_started')
        print('не дожидаться окончания расчетов в скриптов в условии...')
        print('еще что-то делается.....')
```

Здесь мы используем атрибут класса `checker` для хранения флага `processes_started`, который указывает, были ли уже запущены процессы для текущего предложения. Если флаг не был установлен, то мы запускаем процессы и устанавливаем флаг. Если флаг уже был установлен, значит процессы уже запущены, и мы не запускаем их заново.

Comment: да я понимаю что нужно использовать `multiprocessing` но у мен не работает как нужно. Если использовать так как вы написали, то когда срабатывает условие, то пока процессы все не завершаться, дальше не срабатывает `print('не дожидаться окончания расчетов в скриптов в условии...')`, но и при этом мне нужно дожидаться окончания чежду дочерними скриптами. В нутри условия все ок, работает дожидаясь друг друга, но главный скрипт не продолжает работать не зависимо не дожидаясь результата внутри условия.

Comment: Вот тут  меня еще как раз вопрос возникает, а сработает ли так, что пока выполняется условие, будет идти работа дальше и оно снова обратиться к условию, которое должно снова запуститься, но при этом старый запуск условия не факт что закончил работу, будет ли два раза вызванное условие работать не зависимо? (хотелось бы)

Comment: @krolaper обновил код

Comment: а как бы обойтись без чек флага запущенного процесса, у меня в дочерних всегда будет создаваться новое окно всеравно, мне типо нужно все время новая переменная с новым процессом получается?

Comment: как сделать рандомную перменную уже нашел) Спасибо буду тестить